# Error while locally launching GitHub pages Jekyll page

Tags: ruby, jekyll, github-pages

I am building a GitHub pages website using Jekyll. I want to run this website locally but unfortunately I have a lot of errors.

I am running this command to launch my website on localhost

I followed this tutorial : https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/about-github-pages-and-jekyll

```rb
bundle exec jekyll serve
```

These are the errors I get :

```
$ bundle exec jekyll serve --incremental
                    done in 0.376 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for 'D:/melmasset.github.io'
C:/Ruby30/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve/servlet.rb:3:in `require': cannot load such file -- webrick (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby30/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve/servlet.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby30/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:184:in `require_relative'
        from C:/Ruby30/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:184:in `setup'
        from C:/Ruby30/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:102:in `process'
        from C:/Ruby30/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `block in start'
        from C:/Ruby30/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby30/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby30/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:75:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
        from C:/Ruby30/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
        from C:/Ruby30/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby30/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
        from C:/Ruby30/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
        from C:/Ruby30/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
        from C:/Ruby30/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/exe/jekyll:15:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby30/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby30/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

Ask me if you need other indications :)

Comment: Actually the page you want is https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/testing-your-github-pages-site-locally-with-jekyll

Comment: I also used this one but it doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue [with ruby 3 not having webrick by default anymore](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/8523).
The good news are [the issue has already been fixed](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/8524) and it's available from Jekyll 4.2.1.